# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.5.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: .net, exception, uwp, nuget, service-model

I am getting the following error after installing a third-party [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) package and trying to run.

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.5.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Version 4.5.0.4 is not available in the NuGet list. I installed the 4.5.0 version, but it wasn't of any use. How can I fix this?

Comment: What thidpart nuget you used cause this problem?

Comment: Have you tried use this line `Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives` to install the package manually in the package manager console?

Comment: that is from internal team

Comment: if we didnt mention the version it will install the stable version that might not be the above mentioned version

Comment: Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.5.0.4
Install-Package : Project '4.5.0.4' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.5.0.4
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (4.5.0.4:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: for specific you need use this line `Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives -v 4.5.0.4`

Comment: No it has given 4.5.04 not found and installed 4.5.1. When run it gave the same excpetion

Comment: So, the problem may come from your third-part library dependency library.

Comment: I created a pure sample uwp project and installe dthe third party library. No issues found there during runtime.

Comment: Does the project build successfully before?

Comment: build is succes in both cases. runtime exception happens

Comment: It's hard to reproduce your problem without [mcve], we can only tell same basic troubleshooting.  if you can determine this problem related with third-part lib, please go ahead post issue report in github issue box. if not, please post your problem [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/main/release-notes/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.md)

Comment: hmm... iam also unable to replicate the issue in a sample application. Only in the projrct it appears which cant be shared here

Comment: Yep, I know that, you still need check which nuget refer to 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, **Version=4.5.0.4**. And try to change it to available version.